# Changing grouping separator, currency symbol and position of currency symbol for multiple currencies in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

My app uses multiple currencies, and these currencies uses different formats, for example:

Price for **Ruble** shows as: **1,101 Руб.**

Same amount for **US Dollar** shows as: **US $1 101**

How would I change the grouping separator, currency symbol and position of currency symbol,  by defining a set of different formats for different currencies.

This is how my short code stands

```
var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
formatter.stringFromNumber(4500000)
//Output : $4,500,000.00
//Expected : 4,500,000 Руб.
```

Comment: "I am not able to change the grouping separator, currency symbol and position of the currency symbol" You don't need to. The locale takes care of this for you. But if you do need to, have you _read_ the NSNumberFormatter documentation? I don't see you even _trying_ change the format or the currency code.

Comment: You have spent many hours doing what? RTFM. You have two options: use the locale for Belarus (read the documentation for `NSLocale`) or configure the formatter with specific currency symbol, fraction digits, grouping symbol,  etc (read the document for `NSNumberFormatter`). I strongly recommend the former.

Comment: "NSNumberFormatter docs not available in Swift"? That's a joke, right? The development environment is not Swift but Xcode, and NSNumberFormatter is definitely in the docs available in Xcode. It is also available online: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with Currency class that uses current locale decimal/thousands/grouping separators (thanks to @jcaron recommendation in comments)

The class offers few customization, which fits my task:

- Currency symbol
- Minimum/maximum fraction digits
- Positioning symbol either left/right

---

```
class Currency {
    var formatter = NumberFormatter()
    var symbol: String
    var isRTL: Bool

    init(_ currencySymbol: String, minFractionDigits: Int, maxFractionDigits: Int, isRTL: Bool) {
        self.formatter.currencySymbol = ""
        self.formatter.minimumFractionDigits = minFractionDigits
        self.formatter.maximumFractionDigits = maxFractionDigits
        self.formatter.numberStyle = .currency

        self.symbol = currencySymbol
        self.isRTL = isRTL
    }

    func beautify(_ price: Double) -> String {
        let str = self.formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: price))!
        if self.isRTL {
            return str + self.symbol
        }
        return self.symbol + str
    }
}
```

**Initialize required formatters**

```
struct CurrencyFormatter {
    static let byr = Currency(" Руб.", minFractionDigits: 2, maxFractionDigits: 2, isRTL: true)
    static let usd = Currency("US $", minFractionDigits: 2, maxFractionDigits: 2, isRTL: false)
    static let rub = Currency("\u{20BD} ", minFractionDigits: 0, maxFractionDigits: 1, isRTL: false)
}
```

**Usage**

```
CurrencyFormatter.byr.beautify(12345.67) // Output: 12 345,67 Руб.
CurrencyFormatter.usd.beautify(12345.67) // Output: US $12 345,67
CurrencyFormatter.rub.beautify(12345.67) // Output: ₽ 12 345,7
```

Comment: you should initialise your number formatter only once using a struct and static let. You should use Double instead of Float

Answer (score 23):

Swift 4 or later

```
extension Formatter {
    static let belarusianRuble: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        // set the numberStyle to .CurrencyStyle
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        // set the desired negative and positive formats grouping, and currency symbol position
        formatter.positiveFormat = "#,##0 ¤"
        formatter.negativeFormat = "-#,##0 ¤"
        // set your custom currency symbol
        formatter.currencySymbol = "Руб"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
let stringToDisplay = Formatter.belarusianRuble.string(for: 4500000)  // "4,500,000 Руб"
```

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let currencyBYR: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.positiveFormat = "#,##0 ¤"
        formatter.negativeFormat = "-#,##0 ¤"
        formatter.currencySymbol = "Руб"
        return formatter
    }()
    static let currencyEUR: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt_PT")
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
    static let currencyUSD: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
    static let currencyBRL: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
    static let currencyRUB: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        return formatter
    }()
    static let currencyLocale: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = .current
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
extension Numeric {
    var currencyLocale: String { return Formatter.currencyLocale.string(for: self) ?? "" }
    var currencyUSD: String { return Formatter.currencyUSD.string(for: self) ?? "" }
    var currencyEUR: String { return Formatter.currencyEUR.string(for: self) ?? "" }
    var currencyBYR: String { return Formatter.currencyBYR.string(for: self) ?? "" }
    var currencyBRL: String { return Formatter.currencyBRL.string(for: self) ?? "" }
    var currencyRUB: String { return Formatter.currencyRUB.string(for: self) ?? "" }
}
```

---

Usage

```
let amount = 4500000.0

let stringLocale = amount.currencyLocale   // "$4,500,000.00"

let stringUSD = amount.currencyUSD         // "$4,500,000.00"
let stringEUR = amount.currencyEUR         // "4 500 000,00 €"
let stringBRL = amount.currencyBRL         // "R$ 4.500.000,00"
let stringBYR = amount.currencyBYR         // "4,500,000 Руб"
let stringRUB = amount.currencyRUB         // "4 500 000 ₽"
```